# Using buildbot slaves

Tags: buildbot

I saw some waterfall display for buildbot which have builds and tests categorized by device types. How do I get this type of display. Does buildbot automatically generate different columns for different slaves? Right now I am using only one slave and handling the scheduling of tests with python script. Is it possible to use only buildbot slaves to achieve the parallel tests?

Answer (score 1):

In waterfall page you buildbot generates a columns per builder. You can add and configure builders in master.cfg file. Have a look at [this](http://docs.buildbot.net/0.8.12/tutorial/fiveminutes.html?highlight=builderconfig) for more info.

You can achive parallel builds by adding multiple builders to your slave, and in slave configuration increasing max_builds parameter like`

```
config['slaves'].append(BuildSlave('my-slave', 'password', max_builds=5))
```

This will allow you to run 5 builds in parallel for example.